# Как сделать в askopenfilename чтобы не было пути файла, а было только имя файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame, split

Вот мой код:

```py
song = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir='tracks/', title="Choose A Song", filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),))
    song_box.insert(END, song)
```

**P.S.** Синтаксических ошибок нет, просто так вставилось

Хочу, чтобы он не выводил путь к файлу, к примеру:

```
C:/Users/----/Downloads/-----.mp3
```

а только

```
----.mp3
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте `./`. Это означает, что файл находится в этой директории.

Comment: @Корги по имени Никитос ответ помог?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
song = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    initialdir='tracks/', 
    title="Choose A Song", 
    filetypes=(("mp3 Files", "*.mp3"),)
) 
    song = song.split('/')[-1]
    song_box.insert(END, song)
```